# Tools for trusted users

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Allot of people are register, ask and go users on here. It is getting pretty crazy typing in

"Welcome .... Please read the FAQ ... ask a specific question... etc"

A "Welcome" button would be nice that sends the user links to HELP in his notification tool bar (or to his email, like digests that we get about inbox notifications, etc). It could add an appropriate comment and allows the user to rephrase his question before the moderators would assess if it belongs here, Linux or Electronics.. or Possibly duplicate or just completely off topic.

Or just some official copy and paste text?

A flag for mod or something like that.

I know we have the review tool but it still requires typing in similar advisory text over and over.. Editing the question has to be done any way to improve the quality if it seems to have some value for any site.

Comment: There's a chrome/firefox extension that adds a lot of this functionality. But I can't remember what it's called :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go! Courtesy of ManisEarth who dug the link up for me;

https://stackapps.com/q/2116

Comment: A dream come true.... Thanks